# How to plot from a condition and limit number of solutions?

Tags: physics, wolfram-physics

I am trying to plot the band structure of some quantum mechanics problems, but I am really lost. From the math I get the following relationship between q and k

```
cos(qL)=cos(KL-phi)/A
```

A, phi are know quantities. I want to make a plot of KL as a function of qL, with qL real. There is an infinite number of solutions, and some values of KL which are imposible to satisfy (gaps in the graph). I understand it should continually solve the equation, getting only the first n intervals. Any pointers?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Implicit plots can be done using [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to the Dirac comb band-structure, albeit with a slightly different potential. This is typically solved graphically - see e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpRQbDVONzw).

You can shade the valid solutions, i.e. when the RHS of your function has values between -1 and 1, to get the allowed bands. Here's an example with the Dirac comb solution, i.e. $f(z) = \cos(z) - \beta \sin[z]/z$:

```mathematica
Block[{intersectionsTop, intersectionsBottom, pairs, rects, pl, 
  f, \[Beta] = 2},
 f[z_] = Cos[z] - \[Beta] Sin[z]/z;
 {intersectionsTop, intersectionsBottom} = 
  Reap[odsoln = 
        NDSolve[{y'[x] == f'[x], y[-12.5] == f[-12.5] - #, 
          WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[x]]}, y[x], {x, -12.5, 12.5}];][[2,
      1]] & /@ {1, -1};
 
 pairs = 
  Partition[Sort@Flatten[{intersectionsTop, intersectionsBottom}], 
   2];
 rects = {Opacity[.5], Gray, 
   Rectangle @@ Thread[{#, {-1, 1}}] & /@ pairs};
 
 pl = Plot[Cos[z] - \[Beta] Sin[z]/z, {z, -12.5, 12.5}, Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> Thick, 
   GridLines -> {Range[-5 Pi, 5 Pi, Pi], {-1, 1}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> {{Black, Dashed}, {Thick, Black}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Epilog -> rects, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 12.5}, Automatic}]
 ]
```

[image]